# Font specified in CSS work in Chrome but not Safari - why?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I specified a font in CSS - it works and loads correctly in desktop chrome, but Arial is loaded instead in desktop Safari and mobile generally - I'm sure I'm missing something really simple but I can't see what it is.

I'm hosting the site on Github and using a netlify free subdomain as this is an experiment - I'm not sure if that's relevant information.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Karla;
    src: url(.../jsc/Karla-Regular.ttf) format ('truettype');
    }
```

Comment: Have you installed the font on your system? Sometimes I've seen this behaviour when I had it installed, chrome used the system's font but other browsers didn't. Do you see a 404 error in the console? I see you have three dots in the path (.../jsc/Karla-Regular.ttf) instead of two (../jsc/Karla-Regular.ttf).

Comment: Apologies - triple dot was a copy-paste error. No 404 error in console. I have installed the font.

Comment: Have you got the font in all the various formats?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Also, try to use absolute paths for your font files

Comment: Try specifying multiple font files, (`EOT`, `WOFF`) in your `@font-face` , Safari might be having a problem with `TrueType` files.